# vba replace strings with function

Tags: vba, string, user-defined-functions

I have an Excel sheet, with a column (column label as "Label") containing strings representing some items.  I wrote a procedure with UDF to convert the strings in the cells of the column to fit for subsequent tasks.

```
Sub change_label()

Dim i as long, Label as long, LR As long, Cel As Range, rng As Range, WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scope")

Label = WorksheetFunction.Match("Label", WS.Rows(1), 0)
LR = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, Label).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = WS.Range(Cells(2, Label), Cells(LR, Label))

For Each Cel In rng
Cel.Value = ChLabel(Cel.Value)
Next Cel

End Sub

    Function ChLabel(CellRef As String) As String
    If CellRef Like "Printer*" Then ChLabel = "PRINTER"
    If CellRef Like "Ink*" Then ChLabel = "INK"
    If CellRef Like "Ribbon*" Then ChLabel = "RIBBON"
    If CellRef Like "A4Paper*" Then ChLabel = "A4" 
    End Function
```

The function, however, occasionally returns blank cells for strings matching the criteria in it (e.g. a cell containing strings "Printer-AX1283" should be converted to "PRINTER" but a blank cells was returned instead).  Sometimes when I re-open the sheet and re-rerun the procedures, it behaved normally again.

Should I improve my function to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to rewrite your UDF with case-insensitive `InStr` function.

```
For txt in Array("Printer", "Ink", "Ribbon", "A4Paper")
  If InStr(CellRef, txt, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
    ChLabel = UCase(txt)
    Exit For
  End If
Next txt
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.  The InStr function works.